# Flutter firebase error Receiver: "Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Recently I have upgraded my flutter to 2.0 and firebase packages to latest ones. After upgrading them i have refactored my deprecated firebase code to new one. In one of my functions i have got run-time error on **cloud_firestore** package.

**Old one:**

```
  Future popularSearch() async {
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('searches').getDocuments();
    final List<PopularSearch> loadedResult = [];

    snapshot.documents.forEach(
        (element) => loadedResult.add(PopularSearch.fromJson(element.data)));
    popularSearches = loadedResult;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**New one:**

```
  Future popularSearch() async {
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('searches').get();
    final List<PopularSearch> loadedResult = [];

    snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (element) => loadedResult.add(PopularSearch.fromJson(element.data)));
    popularSearches = loadedResult;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Now it is giving this error instead of fetching data:

```
E/flutter (12403): Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
E/flutter (12403): Tried calling: []("query")
E/flutter (12403): Found: []() => Map<String, dynamic>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a close bracket to `element.data`  ===> `element.data()`